# Blob path name provider for WebJob trigger

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a following test code that is placed inside a WebJob project. It is triggered after any blob is created (or changed) inside "cBinary/test1/" storage account.

The code works.

```
public class Triggers
{
    public void OnBlobCreated(
        [BlobTrigger("cBinary/test1/{name}")] Stream blob, 
        [Blob("cData/test3/{name}.txt")] out string output)
    {
       output = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

The question is: how to get rid of ugly hard-coded const string "cBinary/test1/" and ""cData/test3/"?

Hard-coding is one problem, but I need to create and maintain couple of such strings (blob directories) that are created dynamically - depend of supported types. What's more - I need this string value in couple of places, I don't want to duplicate it.

I would like them to be placed in some kind of configuration provider that builds the blob path string depending on some enum, for instance.

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement `INameResolver` to resolve QueueNames and BlobNames dynamically. You can add the logic to resolve the name there. Below is some sample code.

```
public class BlobNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        if (name == "blobNameKey")
        {
            //Do whatever you want to do to get the dynamic name
            return "the name of the blob container";
        }
    }
}
```

And then you need to hook it up in `Program.cs`

```
class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
        //Configure JobHost
        var storageConnectionString = "your connection string";
        //Hook up the NameResolver
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration(storageConnectionString) { NameResolver = new BlobNameResolver() };

        config.Queues.BatchSize = 32;

        //Pass configuration to JobJost
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

Finally in `Functions.cs`

```
public class Functions
{
    public async Task ProcessBlob([BlobTrigger("%blobNameKey%")] Stream blob)
    {
        //Do work here
    }
}
```

There's some more information [here.](http://www.benbrouse.me/blog/2015/02/01/custom-configuration-for-azure-webjobs/)

Hope this helps.